# Why do clustering internal validation indices are decreasing with the number of clusters?

Tags: clustering, validation

I get the same pattern for 3 different indices: Silhouettes, Dunn and Connectivity- as the number of clusters increases, the score decreases.
I am using several clustering methods and several distance metrics, this pattern is the same for each combination. I can't figure out why.

Thanks

[image: Silhouettes scores for increasing number of clusters]

Comment: Your data may simply not exhibit any obvious clusters, i.e., clustering may not make sense at all.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you didn't preprocess your data well, if it doesn't have a lot of clusters, or if there are outliers, the clustering algorithms may fail to work well. So maybe that's happening for you.

Also, measures such as sum-of-squares **by definition should decrease with increasing number of clusters**. The optimum is often achieved when every object is it's own cluster - a useless result. Thus, **do not rely on the measures too much**. They can guide you to *interesing* results (when the measure changed rapidly) and they can detect similar results (little change, not interesting) but **in the end, inspect the result manually**, don't rely on an evaluation number to tell you what is good - it cannot.